# How to write pow to Unit Java (JScience)

Tags: java, jscience

I am using **JScience API** to write units, but I am not able use pow method. How to write pow for unit?

```
Unit<Length> centimeter = SI.CENTIMETER;
//Unit<Length> cm3 = centimeter.pow(3);eclipse suggests to add cast
Unit<Length> cm3 = (Unit<Length>) centimeter.pow(3);
System.out.println(cm3); // prints cm? instead of cm^3
```

Comment: when i print, it prints as cm? instead of cm^3

Comment: Sounds like the console can't handle the character for cubed. I'd say your `pow()` call went just fine.

Comment: I was using mac at the moment, I will try in windows, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a UTF-8 3-superscript?

See also here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b3/index.htm

You can check it by analysing the bytes from `cm3.toString()`

```
byte[] bs = cm3.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
for ( byte b : bs )
{
    System.out.println( b );
}
```

My output (using 3 superscript) of the next string:

```
byte[] bs = "cm³".getBytes( "UTF-8" ); // byte[] bs = "cm\u00B3".getBytes( "UTF-8" );
for ( byte b : bs )
{
    System.out.println( b );
}

99
109
-62
-77
```

If the first byte array has the same bytes as the second, the output is correct, but your console cannot display the character `³`

Comment: System.out.print(bs);// = [B@6f507fb2